# Backbone.js remove model from collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm learning Backbone and for the life of me I can't remove a model from a collection. The collection 'remove' event fires, but the collection appears to remain the same. Here's what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/becamo/edit?js,output

I remove the model from the collection upon click.

Then, the list view is listening for the collection remove event and calls render() again.

I can see from a console.log() that the remove event fires, but nothing changes. And when I inspect the collection variable it's unchanged. I've tried probably 50 variations now whilst searching the internet for clues and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to implement `remove` on the collection -- simply removing your attempt to override the default fixes the issue. So the collection implementation becomes:

```
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: User
});
```

Instead of:

```
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: User,
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('remove', this.remove);
  },
  remove: function() {
    console.log('Collection Event: REMOVE');
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/jefudiyido/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Wow. I only added that so that I could log that it happened. I didn't realize it would override the default behavior (lack of sleep). Thanks so much!

Comment: @Zuko No problem -- if you want to log it, you could add a `removeLog` or some similar method name that doesn't collide with `remove`. Or you could use `remove` and call the parent `remove` too.